# Default Handler implementation breaking on nbsp

Tags: java, xml

I have an implementation of default handler. When it gets to a   in the character data it stops parsing. Is there any reason that it is doing this? Are there additional properties that I need to set in order for it to deal with &nbsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This breaks because the XML entity is not defined. You could add

```
<!DOCTYPE document  SYSTEM "document.dtd" [ 
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> 
]>
```

Or just use `&#160;` instead. (Note the ";" at the end)

Also see [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/characters.html).

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` is not a valid xml entity. You might try replacing it with `&#160;` instead, it does the same thing (non-breaking space).

Comment: It breaks/stops parsing on &#160 as well.